# SIEM Alien Vault recommended method for muting noise

Tags: logging, defense, monitoring, siem

I have installed Alien Vault into my environment and I am seeing a ton of logs going into the SIEM. Upon further investigation, I see that these are being generated by AlienVault itself. I think that these events are noisy and create complacency where I need to see real events. I assume that most people are ignoring these events somehow. I have read online and all I can find is this

[How can i prevent alienvault logs from being shown in ossim ?](https://www.alienvault.com/forums/discussion/2764/how-can-i-prevent-alienvault-logs-from-being-shown-in-ossim)

Judging from the above article , I see that this method is somewhat of a hack.

Here is what I am currently doing . I created two rules for Source of AlienVault and one for the Destination of AlienVault , then set them to No SIEM. Is this a sound practice?

[image]

Is it recommended to silence or mute AlienVault alerts?

What is a good or clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I forwarded the question to AlienVault via e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to AlienVault via e-mail and they sent me the same workaround you described in your question:

> 1.- create 2 policies. 
>   go to configuration -> threat intelligence -> policies.
>   chose default group.
>
> 2.- first policy will have AlienVault Appliance IP as source ip. 
>   click new policy. 
>   set a name for the policy - like ’from AV'
>   on source ip select alienvault appliance asset from asset tree
>   on destination field select any
>   on siem consequence select no.
>
> 3.- Second one, AlienVault Appliance IP as Destination.
>   click new policy.
>   set a name for the policy - like ’to AV' 
>   on destination ip select alienvault appliance asset from asset tree
>   on source field select any
>   on siem consequence select no.
>
> 4.- Reload Policies You should have a red label/button ‘reload policies’  click it.
>
> This will prevent AlienVault to capture and analyse its own traffic.

Comment: Looks like the same thing that I did.... I'll give the answer as it came from AV themselves..